# Как делать панель с вкладками для iOS?

Tags: cocoa, ipad, objective-c, ios

Как в приложении для iPad сделать tabbed panel? Насколько я знаю, ничего стандартного для этого не сделано :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такое можно подсмотреть в приложении Atomic Web Browser. Как видно, они просто добавляют вьюшки в верхнюю панель. Но такой компонент выглядит очень не нативно для iOS.

[image]

**Добавлено.**

Если обновить систему до версии 5.0, то можно увидеть новую реализацию панели со вкладками в iOS Safari. Здесь всё выглядит вполне нативно.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Есть стандартный компонент [UITabBar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH102-SW1). Но это не совсем то, что обычно понимают под tabbed panel.

Answer (score 1):

Да, правильно ничего стандартного для этого нет, но можно пойти несколькими путями. Первый путь - это использовать кнопки для переключения между вью (если это простое приложение); сделать их можно очень просто, а вкладочки или закладочки можно просто нарисовать и поиграться с свойствами кнопок. Второй вариант - это придумать, так сказать, кастомный таббар, то есть отказаться от простого черного таббара и путем нехитрых заморочек создать свой личный и красивый кастомный таббарчик.